# Installing Open MP for Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c, visual-studio, openmp

I have downloaded VS2019 and looks like the omp.h library is already installed, but when I run parallel code, it runs just as a normal program would. So I'm wondering if I have to install the openMp somehow, despite the fact the library is already in there.

Also, when I enable the support for OpenMp(In the project settings), the whole code gets a compiling error, despite it runs ok when the setting is disabled.

Comment: What's the error? A missing library? Or something else?

Comment: At first glance there isn't anything extra to install: omp.h includes vcomp.lib (vcompd for debug) via `#pragma comment(lib, "vcomp")`, and I have versions of these libs for all platforms in my install. They're <30K each so I'd be surprised if this was a separate install option.

Comment: The documentation does say that ["If /openmp isn't specified in a compilation, the compiler ignores OpenMP clauses and directives"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/openmp-enable-openmp-2-0-support?view=vs-2019). So without the support enabled in the project settings you won't see any difference, no.

Comment: Rup, Error MSB6006 "CL.exe" was terminated with code 2. And I don't even know what that exe is, and why code 2.

Comment: So after installing the VS, all I got do is enable the suport for openMp and include the <omp.h>, that's all? It should work?

Comment: I'd guess so, but I don't have a working VS2019 install to hand to try it myself. 2 is normally ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND. There's no more detail here: it doesn't say what file wasn't found? If not, and if you want to investigate this yourself, you could use [procmon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to look for the exact API call that gave the error.